# Can you use Wicked Strike and still get the benefits of the stances?

Tags: dnd-4e

The Slayer stances only benefit normal attacks, but Wicked Strike can be used in place of a melee basic attack.

Or can you even use this ability? I was using the character builder on the D&D Insider website, using a human, and it lets me pick one of the normal fighter abilities for his third at-will, so I'm not sure if it's just confused.

Answer (score 2):

No, the stance specifically says that it interacts with melee basic attacks. Wicked Strike is not a melee basic it is used in place of one. Since the stance is not the power generating the melee basic it should not grant a bonus when Wicked Strike is substituted in.

Comment: Huh. Wicked Strike does seem to be an edge case as the wiki (http://community.wizards.com/charop/wiki/Broken/Fixed) implies: "Follow-up Blow and Wicked Strike

Infinite attack loop. Follow-up Blow allows you to make a melee-basic attack when you hit with a power that is not a melee-basic attack. When you make the MBA, replace it with Wicked Strike, relying on the "in place of" language to allow you to use it as your attack, while keeping it from "counting as" an MBA."

Comment: Yeah, they fixed that with an errata that says you can only use Follow-Up Blow once per round.

Answer (score 2):

**No**

Wicked Strike reads:

> You can use the power in place of a melee basic attack

Which means that when the opportunity to make a melee basic attack presents it's self, you may opt to use Wicked Strike **in place of** the melee basic attack, but in doing so it does not inherently become a melee basic attack, and so the Slayer's melee basic attack damage bonus stances do not come into effect.

Were the power to read

> This power counts as a melee basic attack

You could make a good argument that the Slayer would get to double dip.